# How to convert Date and Time Combination into Days in Java

Tags: java

I have Date and Time combination as `2012-02-28T13:10:50Z` which I got from the WebService.

I need to convert that String into number of Days.

Comment: Number of days from what start point ?

Comment: This makes no sense. A DateTime is a specific spot in time

Comment: Have you tried [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Find the other date and time combination that you need to calculate a duration.

Comment: number of days from 1970 January 1

Comment: [Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the date, use

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

I'm not sure about the trailing Z.

```
date = sdf.parse (d);
// java.util.Date = Tue Feb 28 13:10:50 CET 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the timestamp with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and convert the milli seconds [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) into days by dividing by `24*60*60*1000L` -> number of days since 1/1/1970

Answer (score 1):

You may find this helpful, this is specific to the XML Schema date/time:

[`DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar%28java.lang.String%29)

Follow the link on that page to the class XMLGregorianCalendar for details on how to extract all components.